# How to make a ccs transition only forward

Tags: html, css

I have a p which change from opacity 0 to opacity 1 if you hover a div, how can I make the css transition of .2s only for the "0 to 1" opacity change and not for the "1 to 0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by only adding the transition CSS to the hover state CSS.

### HTML

```
<div></div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

div:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/s2Sb7/